# Как подключить AMP страницу для мобильных устройств?

Tags: php, .htaccess, amp

Есть простая статическая страница формата `index.html` есть её копия, оформленная по канонам [amp валидатора](https://validator.ampproject.org/) назовем её `index.amp.html` лежит в той же директории. Вопрос - Как для людей зашедших на сайт с мобильных устройств отдавать версию amp страницы, а для всех других - обычную `index.html`?

Сайт развернут на php 7.4 Apache HTTP Server

Тут надо что-то прописывать в .htaccess ?

Я читал [документацию](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/amp?hl=ru), но не вижу тут нужного ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте что говорит об этом **[учебник АМП](https://amp.dev/ru/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/discovery/)**:

> **Как сообщать о наличии AMP-версии страницы**
>
> Для некоторых видов
> контента, например новостных статей, целесообразно размещать на одной
> странице как обычную версию материалов, так и вариант в формате AMP.
> Как сделать так, чтобы робот Google, обнаружив обычную страницу,
> обрабатывал ее AMP-версию?
>
> **Связывание страниц с помощью**
>
> Чтобы решить эту проблему,
> добавьте информацию об AMP-странице в раздел  обычной страницы,
> используя теги , и наоборот.

На обычную страницу следует добавить следующий код:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

На AMP-странице нужно разместить такой код:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
```

Таким образом браузер сам определит требуемый линк для размера дисплея пользователя.

Тем не менее **[Гугл предостерегает](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)**:

> Конфигурация сайта с разными URL для различных версий одной
> веб-страницы сложна в реализации и обслуживании. Мы не рекомендуем ее
> применять. Вместо нее лучше использовать адаптивный дизайн.

Comment: Всё добавил как описано, но редирект не производится. Файл с amp версией положил в директорию `amp/index.html` но при заходе на сайт с мобилки отдается браузерная версия

Comment: Дайте нам знать урл с этой проблемой.